# IBM SBT v.1.1.11 method isExpired() in AccessToken is illogical

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, xpages

I think I have found a bug in a method of the IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK in the java class AccessToken. There is the method `isExpired(int threshold)` [image: click here for the image of the method]
The problem is, that the log calls a method of a null object in my case.
So I get a NullPointerException.

Has anyone a solution or a way to solve it?

Comment: Could you replace the image with actual code? If you indent the code with 4 spaces and an empty line before and after, it gets recognised as code and properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest posting an issue on the GitHub project https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/issues. However, I'm not sure how actively the project is being supported.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way to solve that (after posting the issue to GitHub) is to clone the repository local. Move the log lines into the check for null and compile it - the beauty of opensource. You can even file a pull request to move it back.